# how can i add font icon to navbar (ul, li navbar)

Tags: html, navbar, font-awesome

I am almost done, with the navbar, I just want to add 1 font icon, that will open "my account" page.
i tried this:
the navbar looks good, just font is missing.

```html
<header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="_com.html">censord</a></h1>
               <div class="my_account >
    <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
    </div>
               <ul>
              <li><a  href="_com.html">Categories</a></li>
              <li><a  href="_com.html">Post</a></li>
              <li><a href="_com.html">Search</a></li>
              <li><a href="_com.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="_com.html">My account</a></li>
               
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
```

Comment: Where did you specify the font? You have to use font awesome css to display the icons.

Comment: i didn't start to style it , i can't even see it yet, i am using link, <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>

Comment: What do you mean you are using link?

Comment: I solved the problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two points here:

- You have a missing quotation mark on this line, messing up the HTML: `<div class="my_account >`
- Make sure that the CSS property `font-family: FontAwesome` is applied on your `<i>` element.

**Edit:** You can also try to manually set the contents of the `i` element by adding this to your CSS:

i.fa-user-cog {
    content: '\f4fe';
}

Comment: I fixed the quotation mark, it is still not showing up, the font-awesome link is applied.